# Neomake classpath not being set

Tags: java, vim, neomake

I'm having trouble setting my Java classpath in Neomake.

My .jar files are in `~/Github/shadow-blocks/lib`

and .java files in `~/Github/shadow-blocks/src/project1`.

I've tried both

`let g:neomake_java_javac_args = ['-cp', '/home/liam/Github/shadow-blocks/lib:/home/liam/Github/shadow-blocks/src/project1']`

`let g:neomake_java_javac_args = ['-cp', '/home/liam/Github/shadow-blocks/lib/*:/home/liam/Github/shadow-blocks/src/project1/*']`

in my vimrc, but Neomake still throws javac import errors at me when it lints my .java files.

I'm using an expanded home path as there have been issues reported with using ~ with Neomake.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, help very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `let g:neomake_java_javac_args = ['-cp', '/home/liam/Github/shadow-blocks/lib/**']` (and yes, with two `**`s).

Comment: @elliot unfortunately this didn't fix the problem :(
What does ** signify?

Comment: It *should* bring in your jar(s) from the `lib` folder. Are your jars actually there?

Comment: The jars are definitely there.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, I'll try that.